# How to select multiple events (from different groups in horizontal grouping) on ctrl+left mouse click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui

I have a requirement to select multiple events from different groups in kendo ui scheduler with angular js, but currently it only allows multiple events selection in same group. How can i achieve this functionality with kendo ui scheduler in day view.
Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "events from different groups"?

Comment: http://dojo.telerik.com/OHUYU
In above dojo, I want to select one event from Meeting Room 101(i.e. Evaluations) and another event from Meeting Room 201(i.e. Weekly Support Meeting) on ctrl+left mouse click with angular js.